# Prevent wrapping of divs inside scrollable div

Tags: html, css

I have a `div` with `overflow: auto`. Suppose I want to put an arbitrary number of `div` elements inside it such that there is no line wrapping (the additional elements spill into the hidden area and can be scrolled to).

If I knew how wide all those elements would add up to be, I could do this:

```
<div class="scrollable">
    <div class="fixed-width-container">
        <!-- elements float left or display inline-block -->
    </div>
</div>
```

Can I get this effect without knowing the total width of the contained elements?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**UPDATE #2**

Check updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/cyCY3/2/

---

**UPDATE**

Check fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/cyCY3/

---

Specifying a fixed width and `white-space: nowrap` for the child elements should solve the issue.

Comment: Ahh I see -- but how could I get all of the "child" elements in a row? That is more my question than getting an arbitrary string not to wrap.

Comment: Specifying `display: inline-block` for the children and `white-space: nowrap` for the fixed-width container will do the trick. Check the updated fiddle.